# Implementing ListModel with Gee.ArrayList

Tags: gtk, gtk3, vala, listmodel

So I thought I'd be clever one of the more generic and easy to use classes, namely Gee.ArrayList for the data for a ListBox. Turns out that ListBox will take a ListModel, and I figured, since I was using ArrayList, that I might as well just make a class that is both a Gee.ArrayList and a ListModel:

```
public class ObservableArrayList<T> : ListModel, Gee.ArrayList<T>{

    //Implement ListModel
    public Object? get_item(uint position){
        if((int)position > size){
            return null;
        }

        return (Object?) this.get((int)position);
    }

    public Type get_item_type(){
        return element_type;
    }

    public uint get_n_items(){
        return (uint)size;
    }

    public new Object? get_object(uint position){
        if((int)position > size){
            return null;
        }
        return (Object) this.get((int)position);
    }

}
```

This, however gives me a strange compile message:

```
/home/rasmus/Projects/Vala/Test/ObservableList.vala.c: In function ‘observable_array_list_g_list_model_interface_init’:
/home/rasmus/Projects/Vala/Test/ObservableList.vala.c:189:18: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  iface->get_item = (GObject* (*) (GListModel*, guint)) observable_array_list_real_get_item;
```

And while the compilation succeeds, the class is very much unusable as a ListModel:

```
using Gtk;

public class TestApp : Gtk.Application{

    public TestApp () {
        Object (
            application_id: "TestApp",
            flags: ApplicationFlags.FLAGS_NONE
        );
    }

    protected override void activate(){
        var main_window = new Gtk.ApplicationWindow (this);
            main_window.default_height = 400;
            main_window.default_width = 600;
            main_window.title = "test";

        ListModel t = new ObservableArrayList<int>();

        var list_box = new Gtk.ListBox();

        list_box.bind_model(t, null);

        main_window.add(list_box);

        main_window.show_all ();

    }

    public static int main (string[] args) {
        Gtk.init (ref args);

        var app = new TestApp ();

        return app.run(args);
    }
}
```

The output of which, when trying to run a compiled program is:

```
segmentationfault
```

Is there a good way to resolve this, or have i been trying something that was wrong from the outset?

Comment: Can you post a complete/compilable snippet please? I've just spend quite a while working with your code just to find it seems to work so you must be doing something else somewhere else. (This is particularly apparent because your class is `ObservableArrayList` yet your usage and warnings are for a `ObservableList`)

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. I typed the calling of the class from memory, thus it was wrong. I've updated the post with a usage sample now. Please let me know further. again thank you.

Answer (score 2):

An important thing to remember is that Vala actually compiles to C which is then fed into GCC to build an executable, your compiler warning is actually comping from `gcc` not `valac`

On my machine the message is formatted *slightly* differently

```
warning: assignment to ‘void * (*)(GListModel *, guint)’ {aka ‘void * (*)(struct _GListModel *, unsigned int)’} from incompatible pointer type ‘GObject * (*)(GListModel *, guint)’ {aka ‘struct _GObject * (*)(struct _GListModel *, unsigned int)’}
```

Which can be simplified to

```
assignment to ‘void * (*)(GListModel *, guint)’ from incompatible type ‘GObject * (*)(GListModel *, guint)’
```

Which is basically saying that GLib expects get_item to return `void *` instead of a GObject, this is a bug in the bindings so can be ignored

The run comes with the runtime warnings

```
(list:4511): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 21:44:24.003: g_application_set_application_id: assertion 'application_id == NULL || g_application_id_is_valid (application_id)' failed

(list:4511): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 21:44:24.008: gtk_list_box_bind_model: assertion 'model == NULL || create_widget_func != NULL' failed
```

So you have 2 problems

1. Your application id is wrong. Take a look at [HowDoI/ChooseApplicationID](https://wiki.gnome.org/HowDoI/ChooseApplicationID) to help decide what to use instead of "TestApp", generally something like `com.githost.me.App`
2. You haven't actually set a method to bind the model with so Gtk is rejecting it, make sure you actually pass a function there

However neither of those tell us why your getting SEGV

The answer lies in that your GListModel contains elements of type `int` whereas GtkListBox is expecting a collection of `Object`

Comment: "The answer lies in that your GListModel contains elements of type int whereas GtkListBox is expecting a collection of Object" the list box is expecting something that confirms to ListModel, so long as the class it gets implements the methods of that interface, shouldn't it be fine? I mean, otherwise, what's the point?

Comment: You should try boxing the int: new ObservableArrayList<int?>(); That turns it in to a reference type that fits with Vala pointer based generics. Ideally Vala would auto-box, but that needs some work

Comment: GtkListBox expects Object, you can see this in [ListBoxCreateWidgetFunc](https://valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.ListBoxCreateWidgetFunc.html) where the callback takes an Object.

Comment: And can take a null if need be.

Comment: `create_widget`? No it can't, `null` is only valid if the model is also `null` (effectively `unbind_model`). Passing a non-null model but null `create_widget` makes no logical sense and will result in bad things happening